# How to pass context between asynchronous method calls in Python 3.5?

Tags: async-await, python-3.5, python-asyncio

How can I pass context from on asynchronous method call to another one - without using method parameters?

I need the feature to enrich log messages with a kind of flow ID so that I can easily trace all log messages of a specific call method flow.

I use Python's async and await keywords (Python 3.5.x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting a custom [task factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#tasks). It turned out that having a context per task (in comparison to a context per async call) was sufficient for me.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about that one :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Context Variables](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextvars.html) introduced in Python 3.7, and I have a polyfill for Python < 3.7 as [aiocontextvars](https://github.com/fantix/aiocontextvars).

Previous answer:

> You may want to take a look at [tasklocals](https://github.com/vkryachko/tasklocals) and [aiolocals](https://docs.atlassian.com/aiolocals/latest/).

Comment: The documentation of both projects looks promising.

Comment: I found it tricky to do it right especially when using third-party loops offering more efficient ``Task`` implementation -
 here's what I did recently: https://github.com/fantix/gino/blob/master/gino/local.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on [aiotask-context package](https://github.com/Skyscanner/aiotask-context). It's a really simple way of passing context between tasks (called with `await` or `yield from`). If you don't wan't to use the package you can still use the idea :).

I'm working on how to propagate it for the `ensure_future` calls too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import contextvars
c_id = contextvars.ContextVar("context_id", default=None)

def get_context_id():
    return c_id.get()

def set_context_id(value):
    c_id.set(value)
```

I struggled a lot for getting this right. If anyone is still searching for the answer then they can refer here. This works with Python3.7 onwards.

- Create an instance of contextvars.ContextVar.
- Here you can give the context variable name and a default value for that variable, the default value will be used in case the variable is not found in the current context.
- Set the value using the setter and you can get the same value using the getter inside same context.
- Define ContextVar at the top level once, and not inside closures(i.e. functions or class etc.) as garbage collection for context is not proper.